# How do I find location of minimum value within a buffer (around a point)

Tags: arcmap, dem, buffer

1. I have  a digital elevation model (DEM) with a point location defined.
2. I want to locate the lowest height values at a set distance from this point.
3. I envisaged creating a buffer around the point and then locating the lowest height values; firstly is this the best way of achieving this, if not can you recommend another option ?
4. If it is the best way, once the buffer is created around the  point, how do I extract DEM cells with the lowest height values? I dont want to know what their values are, I want to be able to identify the cells and know where the cells are.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: What software do you plan on using for this? if you don't have any specific software in mind, edit your question to say so and you'll have folks also suggest software too (probably free/open source) in any answers.

Comment: Do you want "at a set distance" or "within a set distance"?

Comment: Sorry Im using ArcMap 10

Comment: Within a max distance

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a buffer, then clip your DEM to this buffer (see [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36697/is-there-a-way-to-clip-a-raster-using-a-vector-polygon-without-having-spatial-an) or [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Clip/00170000009n000000/)), and then this clipped DEM circle you can [reclassify](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000sr000000.htm) to show the lowest cells. Or just use Classified symbology in properties.