# How to Clip a DEM and retain DEM format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, clip

I have a DEM file that I downloaded from the internet.  I am trying to clip it to reduce the file size.  So far I have tried two different methods, but neither of them produces a clipped file in DEM format (which I need to pass on to an AutoCAD user in DEM format).

1. I have tried the Clip Tool under Data Management -> Raster -> Raster Processing.  I used another image file for my Output Extent.  The problem is that if I use DEM as the extension under "Output Raster Dataset" it will not run the tool.  I am able to run this tool if I choose TIF, but I need it as a DEM.
2. I have also tried right-clicking the DEM and choosing Data -> Export Data.  I drew a graphic rectangle that I wanted to clip to, and used Selected Graphics (Clipping) for my extent.  With this method, DEM is not an option in the Format drop down menu.  I can use this method to export to a TIF, but again I am looking for a DEM.

My question is similar to this one, but the answers here don't address how to keep the DEM format:
[Clipping raster using vector polygon in ArcGIS Desktop without having Spatial Analyst?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36697/is-there-a-way-to-clip-a-raster-using-a-vector-polygon-without-having-spatial-an/)

Is DEM a proprietary format (like SID) that I can't export without a special license or program?  Or am I missing something else?

Comment: DEM is simply a "Digital Elevation Model" in floating point format.  Commonly these are in .tif format.  A DEM can be a grid, .tif, .img etc.  What is stopping you from writing the clipped results to 32bit floating point .tif format?

Comment: @Aaron I'm not sure what you mean by "writing the clipped results to 32bit floating point format."  How would I do that?

Comment: When you clip the input DEM to your area of interest, the default output will likely be 32-bit floating point format.  In other words, if you export to a .tif, it is still a DEM just in .tif format

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Essentially that's what ended up working - I exported to a TIF and the AutoCAD user was able to bring it in in a similar way as he did the original DEM.  I was partially curious if it was possible to export to DEM and the answers below answered that for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an open format [See Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USGS_DEM) but not one typically used as an Output. I believe GRID is a far more commonly used format for DEM data but that may just be a personal preference. I did find a reference for converting "TO" that format but it is an [old solution](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=11291) (written in Avenue ... the old language used with ArcView 3.X).

A link I found indicated that it may be possible to do this using GDAL (go figure).
http://www.gdal.org/frmt_usgsdem.html 
If you really need to do it this way, that may be your best bet.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GDAL so it sounds like I have some reading to do.  It sounds like the AutoCAD user was able to bring in a GeoTIFF, so the problem is solved in the short term, but I was still curious if this was possible.  Sounds like the answer is - maybe possible, but not commonly done.

Answer (score 4):

The USGS DEM format is a default GDAL input and output format. See this [link](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) for more information.

This means you can "clip" is using the `-a_ullr` command in [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) or use [gdal_warp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html)
using the `-cl` and `-crop` commands.

Here is some code to get you moving

```
gdalwarp -of DEM -cutline C:\temp\area_of_interest.shp -crop_to_cutline C:\temp\input.dem C:\temp\output.dem
```

This will allow you to clip to a vector polygon (shp) without using Spatial Analyst.

Comment: Thanks for the link about GDAL.  I'd like to get more familiar with it, since I'd never heard of it until these answers.  I do not have Spatial Analyst, so thanks for including that work around.

Comment: I think Spatial Analyst is the workaround....

Comment: Ok thanks.  I don't have much experience with code or GDAL so the snippet you provided should get me in the right direction.

Comment: It should be easy enough.  if you are using windows install this version of gdal through OSGEO4W http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/